# Are there any citable Github repositories not published in journals, that receive a lot of citations?

Tags: citations, code, doi, repository

I wish to know whether there is some way, or maybe even some standard, for making a GitHub repository citable in a way that is recognized by academics. Many options have been suggested here, e.g., FigShare and Zenodo, but it seems to me that these routes are not actually established or taken seriously by academics.

For example, I made a Figshare DOI for my GitHub program in 2013 and it turned out to get zero citations, despite the paper related to the code getting many citations. People simply found citing something from Figshare to be awkward so the GitHub repository did not get citations the way an article would.

My question is this: **Is there any practical evidence that some way of making a GitHub repository citable is somewhat accepted? For example, can anyone please point me to any GitHub repositories that have actually been cited many times as recognized by Google Scholar?**

Comment: Hi, user1271772. Welcome to Academia.SE. Unfortunately, what you're asking for is a "shopping question," since you're asking for a "list of X."  A better question might be to ask "How do I get people to cite my online repository?"

Comment: @aeismail: Unfortunately I am not interested in the answer to the question "how do I get people to cite my online repository". Honestly I think you're extending the concept of a shopping question to far outside of what it's original purpose was. I asked this question because I think there might be no examples at all, which makes this question very different from all the types of questions listed in the meta post that you gave a link to. How about if I edit the question to say "Is there any github repository with over 50 citations on Google Scholar without being published anywhere else?"

Comment: @aeismail: regarding my proposed change to the question, your first instinct will probably be that it will "attract a lot of answers", but honestly I think there will not be many answers at all because neither me or anyone I know is aware of any examples. This seems like the only place where I can ask this question to find out the answer. Please let it stay.

Comment: Then the question you should consider asking is: “How do I find examples of highly cited (code) repositories?” That gets you to your goal and still fits within our guidelines.

Comment: @aeismail: I made the change, and then just before hitting the button that would publish the change I re-considered. Are you sure this is the best idea? I cannot imagine anyone answering the question you suggest. The answer to that question seems to be to ask here.

Comment: The guidance provided in the meta link will say essentially the same thing: while lists of things are bad fits for the site, "how to" questions are considered on-topic. (If somebody knows a highly cited repository, how did they find out about it, exactly?)

Comment: @aeismail: I had read the meta link before making my comment 3 comments ago. I may be new here, but I have read the meta link you gave and took time to understand what a shopping question is and why they are unwelcome. All the reasons for rejecting shopping questions do not apply to this question. (1) The answers will not be based on opinion, they will be based on facts (link to Google Scholar page showing citations for a GitHub repo). (2) There is an objective way of deciding the best answer: the one with the most examples or examples with most citations. (3) It won't attract a lot of answers

Comment: @aeismail: There is no threat to neutrality here. A git hub repo either has citations or not. I have never in my life seen a GitHub repo that managed to get a lot of citations on its own without being published in a program journal, yet there are tonnes of questions here asking for how to make a GitHub page cite-able, and those questions attracted various different answers suggesting that there's many methods in place to do this, but the question now is whether or not any of those work. No threat to neutrality.

Comment: Let me just ask the following question. What is the more valuable piece of information: what is the most cited repository, or how to find citations of a repository? The latter question is more generally applicable and of greater use to future visitors.

Comment: @aeismail: Once again, I am not interested in how to find such things, and honestly I'm refraining from asking it that way because I am ***very*** doubtful that anyone will be able to suggest a strategy for how to find such a thing. I believe it would be easier to get an answer to the question I asked. This is because if someone just "happens to know" a highly cited Git repo, they can mention it (without having any "method" for how to find such a thing). In this sense, my question is much more likely to get an answer since any answer to your version will also include an answer to my version.

Comment: But not the other way around. At the moment I'm not even sure there will be any answer to the question I have asked, so making it even harder to get an answer, does not seem like a wise idea.

Comment: *Unfortunately I am not interested in the answer to the question "how do I get people to cite my online repository".* – Okay, but what are you actually interested in? Going by how you framed your question, you are not looking for highly cited repositories for their own sake – making this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). For example, do you wish to see proof that using Zenodo can work? Since there are a lot of factors weighing into what people cite (e.g., whether a peer-reviewed paper exists as an alternative), I see little point in having the list you are asking for.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Well, I ***do*** see a point in having the list that I asked for. It would give me indication that there is some method, or maybe even some standard, for making a GitHub repository citable in a way that is recognized by academics. Figshare and Zenodo do not seem to be taken seriously by academics, but I might be wrong. I have no way to know whether or not I am wrong without this list.

Comment: @user1271772: I edited your question according to your last comment and reopened it. Please check that everything is still according to your intentions.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Well let's see what happens. I personally think this whole exercise/argument was a waste of time and the original question was the best way to ask it, but let's see if we get any answers.

Comment: I don’t understand what the phrase “make X citable” means. A citation is nothing more than instructions to the reader for how to access the resource being cited. Anyone can cite any Github repo by listing the URL; having a DOI is not a requirement. (Some of my StackExchange posts have more citations than some of my journal papers.)

Comment: @user1271772: For what it's worth, one common thing in academia is for people to write a short technical report to accompany a piece of code, and then ask people to cite that.

Comment: @JeffE Your shuffling question has 4 citations on Google Scholar. Is that the SE post that has the most citations? Also just a quick answer to your comment: I originally did not use the word "citeable" that was added by the moderator Wrzlprmft.

Comment: @user1271772 I strongly suspect that MathOverflow has more citations than any other StackExchange site.

Comment: @JeffE I'm referring to your comment "Some of my StackExchange posts have more citations than some of my journal papers." ... is the shuffling question on Theoretical.CS the most cited post of yours?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 10):

The [Keras repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) has an entry in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?cluster=17868569268188187229) with 1254 citations.

I'm not aware of the author having done anything special to make it "citable" though, other than giving an [example in the FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-should-i-cite-keras) of how to cite it.

---

> For example, I made a Figshare DOI for my GitHub program in 2013 and it turned out to get zero citations, despite the paper related to the code getting many citations.

Personally, whenever I wish to "cite a repository", the first thing I do is check the repository's homepage / documentation / FAQ / etc. to see if the author(s) wrote any instructions on how to cite it. If there are any such instructions, I use those since I assume that that is how the author(s) prefer to be cited.

If there are no such instructions, my next step is to see if there is any (peer-reviewed) paper published by the author(s) of the repository that describes / uses / links to the repository, and cite that if there exists such a thing.

Only if there is no such paper do I consider directly citing the github link itself. The implicit assumption is that, unless there are explicit instructions stating otherwise, it is preferable to cite (peer-reviewed) papers over repositories.

Comment: If I try a new search and type Keras, [the link with 1254 citations](http://139.199.62.115/nat123CacheFolder/646F63732E626470742E6E6574/405465ea305a4f908a2a7f6dd805cb53CD30CE37D031CF2FCD38DF31CB3ACC34C534CF_e22880a46b0f1f3f3eb1e14dd5452984/media/pdf/kerascn/latest/kerascn.pdf#page=59) is to a PDF (that happens to be a dead link).

Comment: @aeismail Yeah, I clicked the "All 4 versions" button for that one to get my link. That pdf appears to have been (old?) Chinese documentation (see how it starts with "KerasCN Documentation"), not a paper. The author's google scholar profile is [here](https://scholar.google.nl/citations?user=VfYhf2wAAAAJ). He does have other publications, but none of them are specifically about Keras.

Comment: But how would you know it’s about a repository?

Comment: @aeismail Most people include the github url in the References when citing it. See, for example, this paper: www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v48/gal16.pdf (the first one in the "Cited By" list on google scholar of the Keras entry)

Comment: The Github link constitutes only 53 of those 1254 citations.

Comment: @user1271772 Really? That surprises me. I randomly clicked a bunch of the citing publications and every single one of them had the URL. Either way, I'll rephrase it in that case as "most people **should** include the github url in the References when citing it".

Comment: @DennisSoemers: If you click the link that you gave for the phrase "Google Scholar" then click on the author François Chollet, then click on Keras, it gives a breakdown of where the 1254 citations come from!

Comment: @user1271772 Ah well that's irrelevant. The URL is (or should be) present in the References sections of most papers citing it. Google Scholar can be (and often is) wrong about all kinds of details